# Trouble with appending JS obj values into divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, attributes

I have some divs that were cloned using a `template.` Each div contains a JS object value and clicking on any of the divs opens a modal. I've added the obj value (called "Category Title") into the modals as well, but I'm running into an issue:

1. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU9DD.png) what the div containers look like.
2. If I click on the [first container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6urF.png) (called "Animals") it's coming up as `undefined` in the console.
3. If I click on the [next container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk3p1.png) ("Colors") I'm seeing the Animals data instead. In the console "Animals" is also coming up.

Based on the code below, why isn't the first object value of Animals getting appended to the first div? If I had to guess it has something to do with 0, and if so then I don't know why.

#### JS snippet:

```
// irrelevant code
]).then(axios.spread((cat, lib, admn) => {
     _categories = cat.data.d.results;

     this.loadCategories();

loadCategories(){

    let categs = _categories;

    let $host = $("#host");
      for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
          let $template = $("#template").clone();
          $template.find(".cat-box > .cat-title").text(categs[i].Title);
          $("#cat-box-id").attr("data-category", categs[i].Title)
          $host.append($template.html());
          console.log(categs[i].Title)
      }

$("#modal-id").on("show.bs.modal", function(evt) {

   $(".modal-title").attr("data-category", categs);
        let test = $(evt.relatedTarget).data("category");

        $(".modal-title").empty();
        $(".modal-title").text(test);

        console.log(test); // ----- clicking on first div shows 'undefined'
})
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<div id="template" style="display:none">
      <div class="cat-box" id="cat-box-id" data-target="#modal-id" data-toggle="modal">
          <h3 class="cat-title"></h3>
      </div>
</div>

<!----- Modal snippet ----->

<div class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></div>
```